# Is it possible that a Ignite thick client running outside amazon eks kubernetics env can access gridgain server inside eks kubernetics env

Tags: amazon-eks, ignite, thick-client

Is it possible that a Ignite thick client running outside amazon eks kubernetics env can access gridgain server inside eks kubernetics env.

Unable to connect with the eks

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is not recommended to put a thick client outside the Kubernetes cluster because of a possible communication issues.

But it should work with [forceClientToServerConnections](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/clustering/running-client-nodes-behind-nat) property with some limitations.